# Импорт класса из Python файла; VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, импорт, python-import

Всем доброго времени суток, проблема следующая:

[image: Дерево]

В файле `login.py` при попытке импорта:

`from SauseDemo.pages.login_page import LoginPage`

`from SauseDemo.pages.home_page  import HomePage`

Выдается ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SauseDemo'`
Пробовал прописать пути через `sys.path.append()`, пробовал импорт через `..pages.login_page` (насколько я понял в python3 не работает, но все же) соответствующая ошибка: `from ..pages.login_page import LoginPage ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`, добавлял файлы `__init__.py` (по видимому, не имеет особого смысла в python3 для превращения папки в пакет). Все работает при размещении `login.py` на уровне `SauseDemo`, так что не  понимаю я чего-то элементарного. Самостоятельный поиск решений результатов не дал, так что буду рад почитать ваши ответы.

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ModuleNotFoundError)

Comment: @Acinit , пробовал, не помогло

Comment: @aleksandr первым делом смотрел там, как писал выше - не нашел решения проблемы :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть следующая структура

```
/SauseDemo
    /pages
        main.py
    /test123
        app.py
```

Чтобы вызвать из `app.py` модуль `main.py` я делал вот так

`app.py`:

```
import sys
import os

SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))

import pages.main

print('app')
```

`main.py`:

```
print('main')
```

[Оригинал здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/17393350)

Хоть мне и не нравится данный подход к импортированию, но это работает.

А почему так происходит, рассказывают [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/17393350)

---

Главная проблема в том, что `app.py` не знает о существовании `SauseDemo`, тут важен контекст откуда исполняется `python` в терминале. Скажем если мы в `SauseDemo` добавим файл `m.py` и укажем, что мы хотим вызвать `app.py`, а в `app.py` прописать импорт `import pages.main`, то в таком случае вызов произойдёт успешно.

Структура

```
/SauseDemo
    /pages
        main.py
    /test123
        app.py
    m.py
```

`m.py`:

```
import tests123.app
```

`app.py`:

```
import pages.main

print('app')
```

`main.py`:

```
print('main')
```

---

Для обоих вариантов вывод в терминале следующий

```
main
app
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло! За материалы отдельное (:

Comment: @Greenqa я обновил свой ответ, вы можете конечно использовать *антипаттерн* через `sys` и в каждый модуль пихать вызов родительского каталога, но по моему лучше рассмотреть вариант запускаемого файла (`m.py` в моём примере)

Comment: Очень признателен! Вся структура была заведена, что-бы запускать все тесты из соответствующей папки, которые подтягивают данные со страниц. Так что, ваш ответ более чем полон.