# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'

Tags: python

Вот структура проекта:

```
C:.
├───src
│   ├───pages
│   │   └───main_page
│   │       └───page.py
│   ├───parser
│   ├───requirements
│   │   └───__pycache__       
│   └───base.py
└───venv
```

Пытаюсь в модуле page.py импортировать классы из других модулей:

```
# page.py
from base import BaseClass
from locators import MainPageLocators


class MainPage(BaseClass):

    def search(self):

        self._find_element(MainPageLocators.PLACE)
        self._click_visible_element(MainPageLocators.PLACE)
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
c:\Users\user\project\src\pages\main_page\page.py", line 1, in <module>
    from base import BaseClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста где я ошибаюсь?
Пробовал указывать абсолютные импорты, не помогает. Голову уже сломал.

Comment: попробуйте дать файлу более редкое имя. `base100500.py`, например.

Comment: Попробовал, но как это поможет?...

Comment: кажется мне, что [я давал ответ на подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540243/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-python-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-vs-code/1540251#1540251)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Импорт класса из Python файла; VS Code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540243/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-python-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-vs-code)

Comment: Главная проблема в том, что вы запускайте свой проект из директории, где лежит `page.py`, в контексте нет понятия о папке `src` и их папках